# Showing Files on Android

Tags: backendless

I'm very new to backendless.
And a little bit new to developing an androip app.

I'm trying to show list of files in my Backendless to my Android app.

I'm trying to show my uploaded files in my Backendless to a List View in my Android Studio Project. Wherein the user could see the files(images,documents,pdf) inside the folder and other sub folders inside it.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! what have you tried so far? please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to learn how to ask good questions on SO

Comment: and add those things to your question, don't post it as a comment in response

Answer (score 0):

Backendless cares about you even if you are "very new" to it :)

Just use it`s build-in code generation tool. It already provides you a file manager for you application. You can customize it so that would pass for all your needs.

Well, open console and create your new app. Then go to Code Generation section, select Android tab and check "Simple file manager" option.

[image]

As soon as you you download the project open it in your IDE, select SDK and run.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But the code generation from Backendless Console only gives a Image upload and shows only Images. I'm looking for a way to show not only images but also documents, pdf's and powerpoints.

Comment: Maybe this file service example would be helpful. https://github.com/Backendless/Android-SDK/tree/master/samples/FileService/filedemo

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

https://github.com/Backendless/Android-SDK/blob/master/src/com/backendless/Files.java

This has all the codes you need concerning file management for backendless in your android project.